# Spring MVC - won't redirect after saving to database

Tags: html, spring-mvc

im fairly new to Spring and Thymeleaf and trying to learn a bit about it.
 I'm trying to pass data from two simple input fields from my site to a controller that handles a POST which saves the data to a NoSQL MongoDB and then redirects back to another controller which handles get requests on Root.

My code saves to the Database just fine, but does not rededirect, am I doing anything wrong, or does anybody know a way to do this?

Controller Class

```
@Controller
public class AppController {


@Autowired
PersonRepository personRepository;


@RequestMapping(path = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView index(){
    ModelAndView modView = new ModelAndView("index");
    modView.addObject("personList", personRepository.findAll());
    return modView;
}

@RequestMapping(path = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String addPerson(@RequestParam(value = "fornavn") String fornavn, @RequestParam(value="etternavn") String etternavn){
    personRepository.save(new Person(fornavn,etternavn));
    return "redirect:/";
}
}
```

Comment: Remove  **@ResponseBody**  and,try again

Comment: It still wont work

Comment: What is the response or  any error message

Comment: inject this **HttpServletResponse**

Comment: No error message, it simply doesnt run the redirect, wont load any other HTML document either, I'll try the HttpServletResponse